# Replace all smart quotes in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML document and I want to replace all smart quotes with regular quotes.  I tried this:

```
for text_element in html.findAll():
    content = text_element.string
    if content:
        new_content = content \
            .replace(u"\u2018", "'") \
            .replace(u"\u2019", "'") \
            .replace(u"\u201c", '"') \
            .replace(u"\u201d", '"') \
            .replace("e", "x")
        text_element.string.replaceWith(new_content)
```

(with the e/x transformation just to make it easy to see if things were working or not)

but this is my output:

```
<p>
 This amount of investment is producing results: total final consumption in IEA countries is estimated to be
   <strong>
      60% lowxr
   </strong>
 today because of energy efficiency improvements over the last four decades. This has had the effect of
   <strong>
      avoiding morx xnxrgy consumption than thx total final consumption of thx Europxan Union in 2011
   </strong>
 .
</p>
```

It seems the BS is drilling down to the child-est tags, but I need to get all the text in the entire page.

Comment: What happens if you call: `new_content = str(html).replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(...` ?

Comment: The problem isn't the replace part--it's working correctly on child elements, just not hitting parents.

Comment: That's why I was wondering what happens if you just call it on the entire soup? Maybe I'm missing something though?

Comment: I have a script on GitHub where I use a dictionary to invoke multiple changes to lines in a file, and save those results (in situ): "hn.py" at https://github.com/victoriastuart/hacker_news_scraper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting and filtering all the elements/tags, you could just select the text nodes directly by specifying `True` for the [`string` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument):

```
for text_node in soup.find_all(string=True):
  # do something with each text node
```

As the documentation states, the `string` argument is new in version 4.4.0, which means that you may need to use the `text` argument instead depending on your version:

```
for text_node in soup.find_all(text=True):
  # do something with each text node
```

Here is the relevant code for replacing the values:

```
def remove_smart_quotes (text):
  return text.replace(u"\u2018", "'") \
             .replace(u"\u2019", "'") \
             .replace(u"\u201c", '"') \
             .replace(u"\u201d", '"')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for text_node in soup.find_all(string=True):
  text_node.replaceWith(remove_smart_quotes(text_node))
```

As a side note, the Beautiful Soup documentation actually has a [section on smart quotes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#smart-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

This works, but maybe there is a cleaner way:

```
for text_element in html.findAll():
    for child in text_element.contents:
        if child:
            content = child.string
            if content:
                new_content = remove_smart_quotes(content)
                child.string.replaceWith(new_content)
```